# Re-configuring SERCOM port of existing example

Tags: arm, atmel, atmelstudio

I hope this is a right community to post this question, I have Atsamd21-Xplained-Pro kit and using MSC (USB) example from the list, I can now able to access SD card content on my computer via USB. I want to change SPI SERCOM port of SD card to another one. How can i change that.?
Can i import this project to Atmel START and re-configure the SERCOM port.? if 'yes' the how.? OR please provide any other better way!

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the "USB MSC" example from "Atmel Start Example Project"? This project uses USB as a mass storage, which uses 22k bytes internal RAM as a virtual disk, it doesn't use the SD.

Comment: I have configured that example to work with SD cards.

Comment: Then you should share the code that you have modified.